# How can I insert the text of one cell into another?

Tags: google-sheets

Scenario:

I have one cell designated as a variable (e.g. 3) and certain columns rely on it for calculations. I want the header to have the value of the 'variable cell.'

E.g.

```
 -----------------------------------------------
 |   A       |   B          |   C   |   D      |
 -----------------------------------------------
1| Heading A | Heading %D2% |       | Variable |
2| 3.55      | 4,523.66     |       |    3     |
3| 21.7      | 6,111.25     |       |          |
4| 41.9      | 1,591.47     |       |          |
------------------------------------------------
```

...where %D2% designates text from cell D2 (i.e. "3")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using concatenate.
Example:

```
=CONCATENATE("heading text"; D2)
```

#### Reference:

- [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)